# Problems when generating classes with JAXB - no @XmlRootElement

Tags: java, spring, maven, jaxb, maven-jaxb2-plugin

When I run the JAXB plugin, the files are created, but without @XmlRootElement for this reason I need to include this annotation manually in addition to adding an "extends" to the class, however whenever the project is updated the change is undone:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class BuscarVeiculo extends BuscarGenericDao {
```

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.14.0</version>               
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>veiculo</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>                    
                    <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl</schemaDirectory>
                        <schemaIncludes>
                            <include>VeiculoWS.wsdl</include>
                        </schemaIncludes>
                        <generatePackage>com.pmdf.soap.api.soap.project.veiculo</generatePackage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</generateDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>    
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

In the code below I make the call:

```
@Service
public class SoapClientService {

    @Autowired
    private Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller;

    private WebServiceTemplate template;

    public JAXBElement<?>  findMyObject(FindGenericDao request, String URI) {

        template = new WebServiceTemplate(marshaller);
        JAXBElement<?> vehicle = (JAXBElement<?>) template.marshalSendAndReceive(URI , request);

        return vehicle;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: You're generating from a WSDL. The XML schema in a WSDL doesn't need a root element declaration, because the XML payload of a SOAP message is nested inside other XML elements. It's doing what it's supposed to. If you're doing SOAP, you should use a library for that, so you don't have to JAXB it yourself.

Comment: But when I run the project he says I need to add @XmlRootElement

Comment: Because JAXB needs a root element, but SOAP doesn't. As I said, if your doing SOAP, use a SOAP library, don't try to build SOAP messages yourself with JAXB.

Comment: Thank you, that really is it.

Answer (score 0):

I was using the wrong plugin to deal with wsdl, in fact I should use jaxws-maven-plugin.